# kafka connect-standalone got hang at after (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:376)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I tried to use kafka-connect to capture changes from mySQL. I use confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc with mysql driver for this case.
However, when starting kafka-connect by executing connect-standalone.sh, it got hang as per the log and nothing showed up. Could you please help me why this happen and how to fix it?

Log when start kafka-connect

```
[2023-03-14 14:43:49,701] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Attempting to open connection #1 to MySql (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:80)
[2023-03-14 14:43:49,702] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] --------------- START GETTING CONNECTION (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:250)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,118] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] --------------- STOP GETTING CONNECTION (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:252)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,121] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Starting thread to monitor tables. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread:82)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,123] DEBUG [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Using MySql dialect to check support for [TABLE] (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:481)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,124] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values: 
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = jdbc_source_mysql_03
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig:376)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,125] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values: 
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = jdbc_source_mysql_03
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:376)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,132] DEBUG [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Used MySql dialect to find table types: [TABLE] (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:500)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,132] DEBUG [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Using MySql dialect to get TABLE (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:429)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,156] DEBUG [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Used MySql dialect to find 1 TABLE (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:442)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,157] DEBUG [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Got the following tables: ["mytestdb"."test11"] (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread:176)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,157] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] --------------- START GETTING CONNECTION (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:250)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,183] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] --------------- STOP GETTING CONNECTION (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect:252)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,185] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] SourceConnectorConfig values: 
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = jdbc_source_mysql_03
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig:376)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,189] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] EnrichedConnectorConfig values: 
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = jdbc_source_mysql_03
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:376)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,187] DEBUG [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Based on the supplied filtering rules, the tables available to read from include: `mytestdb`.`test11` (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread:127)
[2023-03-14 14:43:50,190] DEBUG [jdbc_source_mysql_03|worker] Based on the supplied filtering rules, the tables available to read from include: `mytestdb`.`test11` (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread:127)
[2023-03-14 14:53:48,918] DEBUG node0 scavenging sessions (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:241)
[2023-03-14 14:53:48,918] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler2025928493==dftMaxIdleSec=-1 scavenging sessions (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:1251)
[2023-03-14 14:53:48,919] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler2025928493==dftMaxIdleSec=-1 scavenging session ids [] (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:1259)
[2023-03-14 14:53:48,919] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache@44bd4b0a[evict=-1,removeUnloadable=false,saveOnCreate=false,saveOnInactiveEvict=false] checking expiration on [] (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:688)
```

connect-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=172.22.10.21:9092,172.22.10.22:9092,172.22.10.23:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/app/plugin
```

source-connector.properties

```
name=jdbc_source_mysql_03
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://172.22.10.24:3306/mytestdb
connection.user=mytest
connection.password=password
numeric.mapping=best_fit
tasks.max=1
mode=incrementing
#timestamp.column.name=modifiedAt
incrementing.column.name=id
table.whitelist=mytestdb.test11
table.types=TABLE
timestamp.initial=-1
topic.prefix=mysql1.mytestdb.
table.poll.interval.ms=5000
errors.log.enable=true
```

Comment: what is the status of the connector?, something to try on top of my head, change the key.converter to `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` instead of `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`

Comment: the status was not started, but just hang. I added the properties key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter. It didn't work.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? The connector is running, so add records to your database to get more logs

Comment: I set log at debug level. when it works, I will see the connector keep querying database. However sometimes, it got hang, and nothing showed up.